# Prove that $\frac{a}{ab+c+1}+\frac{b}{bc+a+1}+\frac{c}{ca+b+1} \geqslant 1\,,\;a,b,c > 0\,$ and $\,ab+bc+ca=3\,.$

Tags: inequality

Let $\;a,b,c>0 :\,ab+bc+ca=3\,.\;$ Prove that

$$\dfrac{a}{ab+c+1}+\dfrac{b}{bc+a+1}+\dfrac{c}{ca+b+1}\geqslant1\,.$$

My friend ask me this problem, I tried, but it's very hard.

If we use C-S:
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{a}{ab+c+1} \geqslant\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+a+b+c+ab+bc+ca}\;,$$
then the following is not true.
If we full expanding:
$$ab^3+bc^3+ca^3+11abc+2abc(a+b+c)-19+(a+b+c)^2-abc(a+b+c)^2-(abc)^2 \geqslant0,$$
which $\;ab^3+bc^3+ca^3$ is very uncomfortable :(.

I hope anyone will help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inequality is false for several values of $\,a\,,\,b\,,\,c\,.$

For example, for $\,a=\dfrac1{125}\,,\,$ $\,b=\dfrac52\,,\,$ $\,c=\dfrac{745}{627}\,,$

it results that

$\begin{align}ab+bc+ca&=\dfrac1{50}\!+\!\dfrac{3725}{1254}\!+\!\dfrac{149}{15675}=\dfrac{627\!+\!93125\!+\!298}{31350}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{94050}{31350}=3\;\;,\end{align}$

moreover ,

$\dfrac a{ab+c+1}+\dfrac b{bc+a+1}+\dfrac c{ca+b+1}=$

$=\dfrac{\frac1{125}}{\frac1{125}\!\cdot\!\frac52\!+\!\frac{745}{627}\!+\!1}+\dfrac{\frac52}{\frac52\!\cdot\!\frac{745}{627}\!+\!\frac1{125}\!+\!1}+\dfrac{\frac{745}{627}}{\frac{745}{627}\!\cdot\!\frac1{125}\!+\!\frac52\!+\!1}=$

$=\dfrac{\frac1{125}}{\frac1{50}+\frac{745}{627}+1}+\dfrac{\frac52}{\frac{3725}{1254}+\frac1{125}+1}+\dfrac{\frac{745}{627}}{\frac{149}{15675}+\frac52+1}=$

$=\dfrac{\frac1{125}}{\frac{627+37250+31350}{31350}}+\dfrac{\frac52}{\frac{465625+1254+156750}{156750}}+\dfrac{\frac{745}{627}}{\frac{298+78375+31350}{31350}}=$

$=\dfrac{\frac1{125}}{\frac{69227}{31350}}+\dfrac{\frac52}{\frac{623629}{156750}}+\dfrac{\frac{745}{627}}{\frac{110023}{31350}}=$

$=\dfrac{1254}{346135}+\dfrac{391875}{623629}+\dfrac{37250}{110023}=$

$=\dfrac{23050521413573243}{23749545406600045}<1\,.$

Comment: Oh well :). So it’s wrong, many thanks!